# How to resolve error? 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks' in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Currently, I am using Google Colab to run the GAN model where the keras==2.3.1 and tensorflow==2.2.0rc2 have been installed but I am getting the following error how do I make it resolve it:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-04-09 18:41:28.853038: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/pix2pix.py", line 222, in <module>
    gan = Pix2Pix()
  File "drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/pix2pix.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
  File "drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/pix2pix.py", line 138, in build_discriminator
    d1 = d_layer(combined_imgs, self.df, bn=False)
  File "drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/pix2pix.py", line 126, in d_layer
    d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 475, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1441, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

How do I make it resolve? that is produced when I am running the following code in google colab with keras==2.3.1 and tensorflow==2.2.0rc2:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import scipy
# from keras.datasets import mnist
# from keras_contrib.layers.normalization.instancenormalization import InstanceNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
# from keras.optimizers import Adam
# from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
# from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import sys
from data_loader import DataLoader
import numpy as np
import os

# os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf


class Pix2Pix():
    def __init__(self):
        # Input shape
        self.img_rows = 256
        self.img_cols = 256
        self.channels = 3
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)

        # Configure data loader
        self.dataset_name = 'nayadata'
        self.data_loader = DataLoader(dataset_name=self.dataset_name,
                                      img_res=(self.img_rows, self.img_cols))

        # Calculate output shape of D (PatchGAN)
        patch = int(self.img_rows / 2 ** 4)
        self.disc_patch = (patch, patch, 1)

        # Number of filters in the first layer of G and D
        self.gf = 64
        self.df = 64

        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        # Build and compile the discriminator
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

        # -------------------------
        # Construct Computational
        #   Graph of Generator
        # -------------------------

        # Build the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        # Input images and their conditioning images
        img_A = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
        img_B = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # By conditioning on B generate a fake version of A
        fake_A = self.generator(img_B)

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False  # disabled by me

        # Discriminators determines validity of translated images / condition pairs
        valid = self.discriminator([fake_A, img_B])

        self.combined = Model(inputs=[img_A, img_B], outputs=[valid, fake_A])
        self.combined.compile(loss=['mse', 'mae'], loss_weights=[1, 100], optimizer=optimizer)

    def build_generator(self):
        """U-Net Generator"""

        def conv2d(layer_input, filters, f_size=1, bn=True):
            """Layers used during downsampling"""
            d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
            d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
            if bn:
                d = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d)
            return d

        def deconv2d(layer_input, skip_input, filters, f_size=4, dropout_rate=0):
            """Layers used during upsampling"""
            u = UpSampling2D(size=2)(layer_input)
            u = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(u)
            if dropout_rate:
                u = Dropout(dropout_rate)(u)
            u = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(u)
            u = Concatenate()([u, skip_input])
            return u

        # Image input
        d0 = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # Downsampling
        d1 = conv2d(d0, self.gf, bn=False)
        d2 = conv2d(d1, self.gf * 2)
        d3 = conv2d(d2, self.gf * 4)
        d4 = conv2d(d3, self.gf * 8)
        d5 = conv2d(d4, self.gf * 8)
        d6 = conv2d(d5, self.gf * 8)
        d7 = conv2d(d6, self.gf * 8)

        # Upsampling
        u1 = deconv2d(d7, d6, self.gf * 8)
        u2 = deconv2d(u1, d5, self.gf * 8)
        u3 = deconv2d(u2, d4, self.gf * 8)
        u4 = deconv2d(u3, d3, self.gf * 4)
        u5 = deconv2d(u4, d2, self.gf * 2)
        u6 = deconv2d(u5, d1, self.gf)

        u7 = UpSampling2D(size=2)(u6)
        output_img = Conv2D(self.channels, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='same', activation='tanh')(u7)

        return Model(d0, output_img)

    def build_discriminator(self):

        def d_layer(layer_input, filters, f_size=4, bn=True):
            """Discriminator layer"""
            d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
            d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
            if bn:
                d = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d)
            return d

        img_A = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
        img_B = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # Concatenate image and conditioning image by channels to produce input
        combined_imgs = Concatenate(axis=-1)([img_A, img_B])

        d1 = d_layer(combined_imgs, self.df, bn=False)
        d2 = d_layer(d1, self.df * 2)
        d3 = d_layer(d2, self.df * 4)
        d4 = d_layer(d3, self.df * 8)

        validity = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='same')(d4)

        return Model([img_A, img_B], validity)

    def train(self, epochs, batch_size=1, sample_interval=50):

        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Adversarial loss ground truths
        valid = np.ones((batch_size,) + self.disc_patch)
        fake = np.zeros((batch_size,) + self.disc_patch)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print(epoch)
            for batch_i, (imgs_A, imgs_B) in enumerate(self.data_loader.load_batch(batch_size)):
                print("yes")
                # ---------------------
                #  Train Discriminator
                # ---------------------
                # os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
                # Condition on B and generate a translated version
                fake_A = self.generator.predict(imgs_B)

                # Train the discriminators (original images = real / generated = Fake)
                d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([imgs_A, imgs_B], valid)
                d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([fake_A, imgs_B], fake)
                d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

                # -----------------
                #  Train Generator
                # -----------------

                # Train the generators
                g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch([imgs_A, imgs_B], [valid, imgs_A])

                elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
                # Plot the progress
                print("[Epoch %d/%d] [Batch %d/%d] [D loss: %f, acc: %3d%%] [G loss: %f] time: %s" % (
                epoch, epochs, batch_i,
                self.data_loader.n_batches,
                d_loss[0],
                100 * d_loss[1],
                g_loss[0],
                elapsed_time))

                # If at save interval => save generated image samples
                if batch_i % sample_interval == 0:
                    self.sample_images(epoch, batch_i)
            if epoch > 2:
                self.generator.save("/content/drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/model_gen/gen_{}.h5".format(epoch))

    def sample_images(self, epoch, batch_i):
        # os.makedirs('/DATA/output/%s' % self.dataset_name, exist_ok=True)
        r, c = 3, 3

        imgs_A, imgs_B = self.data_loader.load_data(batch_size=3, is_testing=True)
        fake_A = self.generator.predict(imgs_B)

        gen_imgs = np.concatenate([imgs_B, fake_A, imgs_A])

        # Rescale images 0 - 1
        gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5

        titles = ['Condition', 'Generated', 'Original']
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                axs[i, j].imshow(gen_imgs[cnt])
                axs[i, j].set_title(titles[i])
                axs[i, j].axis('off')
                cnt += 1
        fig.savefig(
            "/content/drive/My Drive/Code_For_GAN5_new/output/%s/%d_%d.png" % (self.dataset_name, epoch, batch_i))
        plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    # print("physical_devices-------------", len(physical_devices))
    # tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
    gan = Pix2Pix()
    gan.train(epochs=101, batch_size=2, sample_interval=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem of mixing keras and tensorflow, to resolve this I just remove keras and add the syntax as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import scipy
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from data_loader import DataLoader
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, LeakyReLU, UpSampling2D
```